# Reducing power consumption of Intel chipset

Tags: power-management, battery

I've just installed Xubuntu on my Samsung 530U (SSD version) and everything works find, but the battery life is dramatically lower comparing to Win7. Full battery is able to work about ten hours (lowest brightness, wifi/BT turned off, just typing in texworks), but using Xubuntu I get max about 7 hours.

I guess I know, where is the problem, here is my list from powertop:

```
 Bad           Enable SATA link power management for /dev/sda
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
 Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
```

I tried (hard) to find out solution, but nothing work at all. Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: did you try Juptier 
give it try 
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/03/jupiter-applet-officially-switches-to.html

Comment: I tried it and nothing changed.

Comment: try that too ... sorry for trying too much but you should do that for finding solution [PowerTOP 1.97](http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/01/powertop-1-97-tool-saving-power-designed-for-intel-hardware-platforms.html) and you cant get a report about usage of your battery

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not understand what are you trying to say. 
If you mean how looks those "PCI Device..." in Device stats at PowerTOP, there is usage 100% on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try laptop mode tools. You properbly need to read a bit about it. I use it and with that I come close to windows battery life.

I don't know about xubuntu, but in ubuntu you can do;

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

and install it. laptop mode tools should make most of those 'bad' into 'good'

Do you have another graphics card in your laptop ?

EDIT:
In powertop you can also see how many watt is approximately used. You can also see this using battercare in windows. You can use this to compare under different circumstances/loads. And it's a bit fun. :)

Comment: Yes, I know I can find out power consumption in watts. That's the problem - in Windows it is about 4 watts, in Xubuntu about 7.5 watts.

I don't have any other card, just integrated HD 3000 in my SB i5.

And I read laptop-mode-tools are generally for reducing spins of HDD. I have SSD (so no spins :D ), is it really usefull?

Comment: I think I read somewhere that laptop-mode-tools also can be used on SSD. I just got a new computer and have installed ubuntu on a small SSD, and to me it seems like laptop-mode-tools have helped.

But it is up to you if you try. I need to stress I am no expert. :)

Comment: So I tried laptop-mode-tools and it make much better. But still it is not as on the Win 7. Do you think there is a way how to get same battery life?